# Can I animate the opacity of a CSS background-image?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, opacity

CSS/Javascript is not my strong point so I would like to ask if is possible to change the background-image opacity to, let's say, 0.5.

I have a div with

```
background-image: url(images/nacho312.png);
background-position: -50px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
```

but when I load a certain view it does not look very good, so I want to have a "half-disolve" effect when that view is shown. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start.

```
var element = document.getElementById('hello'),
    targetOpacity = 0.5,
    currentOpacity,
    interval = false,


interval = setInterval(function() {

   currentOpacity = element.getComputedStyle('opacity');

   if (currentOpacity > targetOpacity) {
      currentOpacity -= 0.1;
      element.style.opacity = currentOpacity;

   } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
   }


}, 100);
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MjYJC/).

Run this on `window.onload = function() { }` or research cross browser on DOM ready events.

Of course, it is much easier with a library like jQuery.

```
$(function() {
   $('hello').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
});
```

This relies on your container's children inheriting the opacity. To do it without affecting them is a bit of a pain, as you can't reset children's opacity via `opacity: 1`.

Comment: Is there a reason I cannot reset opacity to 1?

Comment: @nacho4d Do you mean with CSS? You can't because elements inherit their ancestor's `opacity`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to animate smoothly and without doing too much extra work - this is a good task for jQuery (or another, similar library).

With jQuery [you could do](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

```
$('#id_of_div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
```

To get a fast animated fade effect on the relevant DIV.

**Update:** if you want to actually fade the background image, but not any foreground contents of the DIV, this is a lot harder.  I'd recommend using one container DIV with position:relative and two inner DIVs with position:absolute; .  The first of the inner DIVs can have the background image and a lower z-index than the second of the DIVs, and the second DIV would contain any text, etc. to show in foreground. When needed you can call `$('#id_of_first_div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);` to fade just the DIV containing the background image.

By the way, the literal answer to your question is "No, you cannot animate the opacity of a CSS background image" - you can only (currently) animate the opacity of a DOM element, not its attributes, thus the need for the above hack.

**Other Update:** if you want to avoid using any third-party library, you can handle the fade of the background DIV using approach in [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404962/can-i-animate-the-opacity-of-a-css-background-image/4405050#4405050).

Comment: The question is not tagged `[jquery]`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was about to say, I got contained divs faded as well. So, I see now that I need a div specially for my background image, right? Thanks ;)

Comment: @alex: it is tagged Javascript and jQuery is coded in Javascript.  When performing actions like animation, it can be very useful to use a library that implements these features (and fancy things like easing, etc. for those who want it). "Pure" Javascript is also of course a valid option.

Comment: @Ben I still think including a library simply to perform this task is overkill.

Comment: @alex Well you might have a point there - if there's no other use for a library in the page, it can definitely be a waste of bandwidth, and some combination of your solution and two DIV approach above can work. But... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question/48195#48195

Comment: @Ben +1 for linking to one of my favourite SO jokes. BTW, I love jQuery, but I also love the challenge of reproducing jQuery effects/utilities without the library.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: url(images/nacho312.png);
background-position: -50px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;

opacity:0.5; //for firefox and chrome
filter:alpha(opacity=50); //for IE
```

Comment: There is no animation there (see OP's title).